# YouTube Data API v3: deleting videos using a service account: Unauthorized client or scope in request

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to delete one or more videos using a simple C# app (I intend to use a Windows Service later) and I'm getting this error:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 93
```

Uploading videos works perfectly. For both operations, I use the same initialization method:

```
private static YouTubeService AuthorizeYoutubeService()
{
  string serviceAccountEmail = "...@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
  string keyFilePath = "Warehouse<...>.p12";
  string userAccountEmail = "login@gmail.com";
  if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Secret file not found!");
    return null;
  }

  var scope = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };
  var cert = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
  try
  {
    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential
      (new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
      {
        Scopes = scope,
        User = userAccountEmail
      }.FromCertificate(cert));

    var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
      HttpClientInitializer = credential,
      ApplicationName = "warehouse"
    });
    return service;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return null;
  }
}
```

The difference compared to simply uploading videos, is the defined Scope: *YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload*. When I try to delete a video using it, I get an **insufficientPermissions (403)** error.
So after looking in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete) I've changed it to *YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube*.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
  var youtubeService = AuthorizeYoutubeService();
  foreach (string id in deleteIds)
  {
    var videoDeleteRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Delete(id);    
    var result = videoDeleteRequest.Execute();
  }
```

Where *deleteIds* is a list of 11 character strings containing IDs of existing videos.
I have YouTube Data API enabled in the developers console.
I've installed the API via NuGet, I don't think there's anything wrong with the packages.

I'm quite new to Google development, and all similar questions were about the calendar API.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is reseting the list of apps connected to the Google account and setting it up again from scratch. My app was added 2 times for some reason.